# Position the Check mark to centre of screen

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and trying to build a logout page which should look something like this,

[image: End result]

I gave it a try but I am not able to position the  Icon at the right place and this entire should be enclosed in a box which too I am unable to. This is my code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Thank you!</title>
</head>
<i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="125" height="125" fill="#5D883C"  class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>    
    <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
  </svg>

<body>
    <div style="Width: 800px;
            Height: 300px;         
            margin: 10px;">          
</div>

<span style=
    "font-size: 35px;
    color: #707070;
    margin-left: 30%;
    text-align: center;"> Thank you! We value your support and partnership.</span>
    
<h4>
    <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family:Calibri; color: #707070; text-align: center; margin-left: 45%;">Click here to log back in: 
    </span>
    <a href="/App/Login.aspx"><span style="font-size: 16px; color:#5D883C;text-align: center;">Login</span></a>
</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Need help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a good resource: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, did it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Thank you!</title>
    <style>

html, body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#center
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}

#ty
{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #707070;
    display: blocK;
}

#bottom
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    background-color: #ddd;
    line-height: 40px;
}

svg
{
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="center">
    <i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="125" height="125" fill="#5D883C"  class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
        <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
    </svg>
    <span id="ty"> Thank you! We value your support and partnership.</span>
    <div id="bottom">
        <span>Click here to log back in:</span>
        <a href="/App/Login.aspx"><span style="font-size: 16px; color:#5D883C;text-align: center;">Login</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Run in full page

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working fine but only one thing the bottom also should be enclosed inside the box in centre as shown in picture. I can not figure out how I can merger centre and bottom div?

Answer (score 1):

**You just need to add this in your CSS**

```
 svg{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;

      }
```

**Let me know if it work for you.**

Answer (score 0):

Similar implementation using inline styles as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Thank you!</title>
  </head>
  <i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>

  <body>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
      <div
        style="
          border: 5px solid #f7f7f7;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
            0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        "
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="125"
          height="125"
          fill="#5D883C"
          class="bi bi-check-circle"
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        >
          <path
            d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"
          />
          <path
            d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"
          />
        </svg>
        <div>
          <span style="font-size: 35px; color: #707070; text-align: center;">
            Thank you! We value your support and partnership.</span
          >
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1px; margin-top: 20px;">
          <h4>
            <span
              style="
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: Calibri;
                color: #707070;
                text-align: center;
              "
              >Click here to log back in:
            </span>
            <a href="/App/Login.aspx"
              ><span
                style="font-size: 16px; color: #5d883c; text-align: center;"
                >Login</span
              ></a
            >
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shadow-r25iv?file=/index.html)